# SwiftLocation - Catch Don't Allow?

Tags: swift, cllocation

I am using SwiftLocation and using its inherent functionality to ask the user to allow Location processing:

```swift
SwiftLocation.gpsLocation(accuracy: .neighborhood).then { result in
    switch result {
       case .success(let locationData):
         do some successfull processing    
       case .failure( _):
         do some failure processing
    }
}
```

If the user selects `Don't Allow` the `result` callback is not called so how do you capture that `Don't Allow` selection? I could not find that scenario on the [SwiftLocation](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftLocation) support site or in its examples. Anyone who maybe has used SwiftLocation have insights on how you address the user denying Location processing?

Comment: if you set user doesn't allow from the start, then ask the user if he wants. If he denies your predefined state "don't allow" is still correct. So there is no need for special handling.

Comment: That did not answer the question of handling the situation when the `result` callback is not called/returned.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot figure out how the async method SwiftLocation.gpsLocation returns an error and I cannot seem to wrap the async task properly.

Comment: From the docs of SwiftLocation I infer that you can check manually if authorisation was granted: let currentStatus = SwiftLocation.authorizationStatus